# How to configure vlans with server 2003 DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp, vlan, dhcp-server

How do you configure Server 2003 to handle vlans?  I believe I need to use the IP Helper in DHCP, but am unsure and am unable to find a decent tutorial or guide on doing this.  Can someone help me or point me to a site that has a guide for setting up Vlans in DHCP on Server 2003 std.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set up VLAN's in DHCP directly. You set up a DHCP scope for each VLAN in DHCP and configure the router that separates the VLAN's as a DHCP relay.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I've never done this, so I want to make sure that I understand correctly.  I'll set up a scope in DHCP (192.168.3.x), go to my router and assign it an address in that scope, find wherever it says enable dhcp relay and check a box?  Is there typically more involved than that or is it pretty simple?

Comment: At a very simple level: Your router will need an interface attached to that subnet (VLAN subnet) with an ip address valid for that subnet. You'll then enable the DHCP relay function on the router and that should do it.

Comment: Ok I set up the scope on my DHCP server, but I am having trouble getting the router to pull addresses from that scope.  It either pulls from my current scope (192.168.1.x) or it kicks me out and I have to reset it.  I'm using a Netgear GSM7248 in one building (the one i'm trying to put on VLAN 3 using 192.168.3.x) and that connects back to the core switch which is a GSM7312

Comment: I'm not understanding you. Do you mean that clients behind that router are not getting DHCP assigned ip addresses? When a DHCP client on that subnet requests an ip address the router should forward the DHCP packets to your server based on the ip address (of the server) that you configured in the DHCP relay settings. The router(s) also need to be able to forward the DHCP broadcasts between subnets.

Comment: They are getting DHCP assigned ip address, but they are from the wrong scope.  I apologize if I'm not being very clear I have not dealt with this very much in the past.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Have you verified that there are no DHCP servers on the subnet where the clients reside?

Comment: @msindle ... I am having the same issue.  Were you able to resolve it?